# Kodi app only does not appear on HDMI attached TV, other apps OK

Tags: 18.04, intel-graphics, kodi

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and when I try to run KODI on my TV via HDMI cable, I can see the whole desktop on TV, run every application and see it on TV, everything but [Kodi](https://kodi.tv/). When I run Kodi, I see it only on my laptop.

I've read that one user solved it in AMD's Catalyst Center (he had to install it first), where he changed the settings for Kodi output and switched it to TV.

I have [Intel® Sandy Bridge Mobile](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005526/graphics-drivers.html) on my laptop.
Can I modify it somewhere in the system?
Is there any option to modify settings on Intel graphics?

Or is there any other solution to mirror Kodi on a not-smart HDMI TV?

Answer (score 0):

The drivers for Intel Graphics HD 2000 and HD 3000 are in the kernel of Ubuntu, so to adjust the video parameters, you go to [Settings](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/gnome-control-center.1.html) then choose Display.

Also, a bad HDMI cable can cause this, because with Kodi, you are often watching [DRM protected content](https://www.howtogeek.com/240636/everything-you-need-to-know-about-watching-drmd-media-on-linux/), and bad HDMI cables don't always provide the connection required.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast answering, but in the display settings there are only few options; to swap the displays (which I've tried before), the laptop's display, unknown display and TV display.  And there is Join displays, mirror and Single display option, which combinations I've also tried.

Comment: Tried another HDMI cable? What is the make and model of your TV? BTW, 'dumb' TVs don't add any extra abilities when using them as an Ubuntu display, and Intel driver controls are not as full-featured, as you have noticed.

Comment: Tried 2 different cables, still nothing. But now I noticed some more strange things...On Sony TV I could see all apps and stuff, and on LG TV i can only see the desktop, and apps only on laptop...And I tried all combinations of display switching.

Comment: Really need the LG's model number and the laptop's make and model to take this any further. Please put that in the question using [edit].